# delete and recreate an object jquery

Tags: jquery

I create this piece of code to "detach" and "reattach" my item, but it doesn't work.

Why?

```
$( "#ciao" ).remove();


$('#condizionale').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#velux').is(':selected')) {
    var el = $('#sel-destination-tour').detach();
  }; 
});

$('#condizionale').on('change', function() {  
   if ($('#zanzariera').is(':selected')) {
     $('#sel-destination-tour').append(el);
   };
});
```

I want to delete the item when "velux" is selected and recreate it when "zanzariera" is selected.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dxq3msht/1/

Comment: @Eugenio but why don't you make both condition in same block as both are work with the same event on same block.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `el` is a local variable of the first event handler, i.e. in your second `#condizionale`'s change handler such variable doesn't exist and you will get a `ReferenceError`. Define the variable in the outer context.

Another problem is using `$('#sel-destination-tour').append(el)` in the second handler. After detaching the query will return an empty set as the detached element doesn't exist in the DOM. Use the `el` element and it's `.appendTo` method instead. Also appending an element to the element itself doesn't make a lot of sense. You should (re)append the element to it's target parent element.

```
var el;
$('#condizionale').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#velux').is(':selected')) {
     el = $('#sel-destination-tour').detach();
  }; 
});

$('#condizionale').on('change', function() {  
   if ($('#zanzariera').is(':selected') && el) {
     el.appendTo('#targetElement');
   };
});
```

Also note that you don't need to define 2 change handlers in this case. You can move the logic of the second handler into the first handler and remove the second handler.

Comment: what is '#targetElement'?

Comment: @Eugenio Just an example. It should be replaced with a selector that selects the target wrapper element. If the wrapper element is the `#condizionale` element replaced it with this selector.

Comment: @Eugenio I have updated your code using the `insertAfter` method. http://jsfiddle.net/9r6suvgw/. You can also show/hide the element instead of detaching/attaching it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```js
$( "#ciao" ).remove();

$('#condizionale').on('change', function() {
  var el; //variable declared out side off the both conditions.    
  if ($('#velux').is(':selected')) {
     el = $('#sel-destination-tour').detach();
  }else if($('#zanzariera').is(':selected')){        
     $('#sel-destination-tour').append(el);   
  };    
});
```